# Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'layer'

Tags: ios, swift

I am new on swift as well as xcode and I encountered this following problem and I just have no clue how to create a button with an "action" type while maintain its styling properties? Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

```
@IBAction func butLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func butSignup(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    txtUsername.layer.borderWidth = 1
    txtUsername.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    txtUsername.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    txtUsername.clipsToBounds = true

    txtPassword.layer.borderWidth = 1
    txtPassword.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    txtPassword.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    txtPassword.clipsToBounds = true

    butLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    butLogin.clipsToBounds = true

    butSignup.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    butSignup.clipsToBounds = true

    Bug:
    Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'layer'
    Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'clipsToBounds'
```

Comment: @BorisHuang You need to create a IBOutlet, not IBAction. Drag *from* Interface Builder to the code to create such a reference.

Comment: @Tobias I think the declaration of the button is at the top of the image? I define it as an 'outlet' type before and now I want to change to an 'action'type. But it didnt work for me as soon as i changed them.

Comment: @BorisHuang Actions is code that gets fired on events, such as mouse clicks / touches. Outlets is how you programmatically reference UI elements to set things such as border radius.

Comment: @Tobias right, the reason why I want to change to actions is because I want to create a second view controller and use this button as a trigger to lead to the second view controller. Is there a way to have an action button meanwhile having those styling properties?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a *segue* ?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, I did create a segue but has no idea how to use that Login button to trigger the segue. I thought action will help. If I can use Outlet type to do the job, that will be amazing (aka the transition of the view controllers)

Comment: You are trying to set properties on the IBActions. You need to set properties on the IBOutlets which you are not showing in the code posted in your question.